# C# CS1737 from interface method

Tags: c#, interface, compiler-errors

I'm working on a project that uses a 3rd-party framework, and in said framework there is an interface I need implement. And this is causing me some confusion, because one of the methods in the interface contains an out parameter after optional parameters (CS1737).

i.e:

```
public interface IDummy
{
    void DoSomething(int a = 0, out bool b);
}
```

1)
How on earth did they manage this? They have themselves managed to implement this interface, I just need my own implementation. It might be relevant that this is a COM Interop generated interface. Maybe their implementation is in a language where this is legal?

2)
Is there anything I can do to circumvent this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That is an error generated by the C# compiler -- it's legal to have a method signature in IL which does this. So the fact that it's a COM Interop assembly is very relevant: that wasn't compiled by the C# compiler.

Comment: You can implement the interface without the optional parameter: implement it as `public void DoSomething(int a, out bool b) { }`

Comment: @canton7 Thanks! Seems I that is my only choice at the moment.